# common dispersion in R

Tags: r

I try to use edge R package to analysis my data as following

This is my data frame called subdata

```
                       A                        B                  C                    D              E
1               13707             13866          12193          12671       10178
2                   0                           0              0                       0               1
3                7165                5002           1256           1341        2087
6                8537              16679           9042           9620       19168
10              19438          25234          15563          16419       16582
16                  3                       3                   11                3                  5

genotype=factor(c("LMS1","LRS1","MS3","MS4","RS5"))
y=DGEList(counts=data.matrix(subdata),group=genotype)


design=model.matrix(~0+group,data=subdata)    
y=estimateGLMCommonDisp(y,design, verbose=TRUE)
```

I try to calculate the common dispersion to estimate up and down regulation genes but I get this error message  as following

```
Warning message:
In estimateGLMCommonDisp.default(y = y$counts, design = design,  :
  No residual df: setting dispersion to NA
```

please could any one help me to dissolve this problem , I really appreciate for that

Comment: So you have a single observation for each group?

Comment: yes I have a single observation for each group

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines. In particular, please post the exact command which returns that warning message.  I also strongly urge you to use `dput` to post your data in a manner that allows us to easily reproduce your problem.  And finally,  a **Warning** is not an **Error** message.  Your calculation completed successfully, but as noted, the lack of residuals made it impossible to calculate a dispersion value.

Comment: in the examples counts and data argument are not the same, perhaps that help? `y <- matrix(rnbinom(1000,mu=10,size=10),ncol=4);
d <- DGEList(counts=y,group=c(1,1,2,2));
design <- model.matrix(~group, data=d$samples);
d1 <- estimateGLMCommonDisp(d, design, verbose=TRUE)`

Comment: I really appreciate for your help

Comment: I still have a problem in calculation of common dispersion and I got this  Warning message:
In estimateGLMCommonDisp.default(y = y$counts, design = design,  :
  No residual df: setting dispersion to NA after using this command y=estimateGLMCommonDisp(y,design, verbose=TRUE)